# otool -L filename/path not working

Tags: ios, iphone, shared-libraries, decompiling, otool

I'm running through some various programming/debugging tutorials and uses the "otool" command in terminal. An example is to check for shared libraries. The error is always one of two. I'm running it from the directory the file is located. Typing in just otool give the list of otool "-x" switches. I've gone down the list of switches on multiple files and directories and get the same errors.

What am I missing?

$ otool -L DemoApp

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: DemoApp (No such file or directory)

or

$ otool -L DemoApp.app

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't map file: DemoApp.app (Invalid argument)

Answer (score 4):

you need to point to a final executable file. DemoApp.app is just a directory. Try `otool -L ~/Applications/DemoApp.app/Contents/MacOS/DemoApp`